# How to escape special character ' \ '?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I use php to retrive the data from table and ajax to display the result.

When I search using location for the 1st time, I get the result and the pagination is not working, especially for "istanbul".

The reason is the special character `'\'` added with the address that's taken from Google map.

The URL passed when i go to next page, is

```
http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search/\"http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search?checkin=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&checkout=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&guests=1&location=Istanbul%2C+Turkey&min_bathrooms=0&min_bedrooms=0&min_beds=0&per_page=10&search_view=1&sort=1&page=3"
```

How to over come this problem?

This is the code that I have written:

```
$config['base_url']   = site_url('search').'?checkin='.urlencode($checkin).'&amp;checkout='.urlencode($checkout).'&amp;guests='.$nof_guest.'&amp;location='.urlencode($location).'&amp;min_bathrooms='.$min_bathrooms.'&amp;min_bedrooms='.$min_bedrooms.'&amp;min_beds='.$min_beds.'&amp;per_page='.$per_page.'&amp;search_view=1&amp;sort='.$sort;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using double quotes, you escape `\` with another `\`. If you need to display a `\`, then you must type `\\`, or you could use single quotes.

Example: `echo "\hello\world";` would need to be `echo "\\hello\\world";`, or `echo '\hello\world';`

Answer (score 0):

To escape in php, you must use \\

Try this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search/\"http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search?checkin=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&checkout=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&guests=1&location=Istanbul%2C+Turkey&min_bathrooms=0&min_bedrooms=0&min_beds=0&per_page=10&search_view=1&sort=1&page=3\"
```

Or this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search/\\"http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search?checkin=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&checkout=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&guests=1&location=Istanbul%2C+Turkey&min_bathrooms=0&min_bedrooms=0&min_beds=0&per_page=10&search_view=1&sort=1&page=3\"
```

Or lastly:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search/\\"http://www.mysite.com/dropinn/search?checkin=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&checkout=mm%2Fdd%2Fyy&guests=1&location=Istanbul%2C+Turkey&min_bathrooms=0&min_bedrooms=0&min_beds=0&per_page=10&search_view=1&sort=1&page=3\\"
```

Your question is a little confusing without seeing more code, but those should work.

Comment: Thanks but, Could you explain it?  I amn't clear... Where to add this \\ ... !